# Display reactive tabsetPanel based on user selection in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app in which I have a `radioButtons` widget with four buttons. When none of them is clicked I want the `tabsetPanel` `"tabC"` to be displayed. If "About" is selected I do not want `tabsetPanel` at all and if "`Section A,B` or `C`" is selected I want the `tabsetPanel` `"tabA"` to be displayed.

```
#ui.r
ui <- fluidPage(
    theme=shinytheme("slate") ,
    # App title ----
    titlePanel("Tabsets"),

    # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
    sidebarLayout(

      # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
      sidebarPanel(
        uiOutput("rad")
      ),

      # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
      mainPanel(
       uiOutput("tabers")


      )
    )
  )
#server.r
library(shiny)

server = function(input, output) {

  output$rad<-renderUI({
    radioButtons("radio", label = "",
                 choices = list("About" = 1, "Sector A" = 2, "Sector B" = 3,"Sector C" = 4), 
                 selected = character(0))
  })


  output$tabers<-renderUI({
    if(input$radio=="Sector A"){
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabA",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Constituents"),
        tabPanel("Clusters" ),
        tabPanel("Index")

      )
    }
    else if(input$radio=="Sector B"){
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabA",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Constituents"),
        tabPanel("Clusters" ),
        tabPanel("Index")

      ) 
    }
    else if(input$radio=="Sector C"){
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabA",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Constituents"),
        tabPanel("Clusters" ),
        tabPanel("Index")

      ) 
    }
   else if(input$radio=="About"){

   }
    else{
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabC",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Global"),
        tabPanel("Performance" )

      ) 
    }

  })

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe since your choices have numeric values, you need to compare `input$radio` with a numeric value, for example: `if (input$radio == 2)` for Sector A.

In addition, when no radio buttons are selected, `input$radio` should be `NULL`. You could check for that at the beginning, and if `NULL`, show your tabC.

Please let me know if this has the desired behavior.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

#ui.r
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme=shinytheme("slate") ,
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Tabsets"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("rad")
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tabers")
    )
  )
)
#server.r

server = function(input, output) {

  output$rad<-renderUI({
    radioButtons("radio", label = "",
                 choices = list("About" = 1, "Sector A" = 2, "Sector B" = 3,"Sector C" = 4), 
                 selected = character(0))
  })

  output$tabers<-renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$radio)) {
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabC",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Global"),
        tabPanel("Performance")
      )
    }
    else if(input$radio==2){
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabA",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Constituents"),
        tabPanel("Clusters" ),
        tabPanel("Index")
      )
    }
    else if(input$radio==3){
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabA",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Constituents"),
        tabPanel("Clusters" ),
        tabPanel("Index")
      ) 
    }
    else if(input$radio==4){
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabA",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Constituents"),
        tabPanel("Clusters" ),
        tabPanel("Index")
      ) 
    }
    else if(input$radio==1){

    }
    # Left last else in here but should not get called as is
    else{
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabC",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Global"),
        tabPanel("Performance" )
      ) 
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think this is the answer @firmo23 was looking for, but I can't avoid to ask if the user will never need to see `tabC` again once they select any of the options in the radio button? Becauce once you select one, you can only go back by refreshing your app.

Comment: I agree - and defer to @firmo23 to comment further on intent. I always wonder when information is provided, if it was meant to serve as an example in terms of function, and might be significantly altered in future implementation. A number of other suggestions could be considered, including `return` after identifying `input$radio` is `NULL`, streamlining series of if/else, etc...but depends on intention of the developer.

Comment: great observation! So is there a way to bring back tabC again after one selection is made?

Comment: i suppose there are a few ways to handle, depending on intent. You could add another radio button, and make it the default. Use `selected` in the `radioButtons` statement to make it the default. Then one can go back and reselect this option after making a different selection. LMK if you want me to revise the answer with this implemented.

Comment: @firmo23 to go back to the initial screen you can consider adding a "home" option in the radio button.

Comment: Thanks Ben I did this.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking a little about your app, look at this option using some fuctions from `shinydashboar` package.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)

#ui.r
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme=shinytheme("slate") ,
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Tabsets"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      sidebarMenu( id = "tab",
      menuItem("Home", tabName = "home"),
      menuItem("Sector A", tabName = "sect_a"),
      menuItem("Sector b", tabName = "sect_b"),
      menuItem("Sector c", tabName = "sect_c"),
      menuItem("About", tabName = "about")
      )
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      tabItems(

        # Home tab
        tabItem(
          tabName = "home",
          tabsetPanel(
            id="tabC",
            type = "tabs",
            tabPanel("Global"),
            tabPanel("Performance" ))
        ),

        tabItem(
          tabName = "sect_a",
          tabsetPanel(
            id="tabA",
            type = "tabs",
            tabPanel("Constituents"),
            tabPanel("Clusters" ),
            tabPanel("Index"))
        ),

        tabItem(
          tabName = "sect_b",
          tabsetPanel(
            id="tabA",
            type = "tabs",
            tabPanel("Constituents"),
            tabPanel("Clusters" ),
            tabPanel("Index"))
        ),

        tabItem(
          tabName = "sect_c",
          tabsetPanel(
            id="tabA",
            type = "tabs",
            tabPanel("Constituents"),
            tabPanel("Clusters" ),
            tabPanel("Index"))),

        tabItem(tabName = "about")
      )




    )
  )
)

#server.r


server = function(input, output) {

}



shinyApp(ui, server)
```